# Visual studio 2010 external library API documentation

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I use external library like Spring.Net, NUnit, NLog and etc. I don't see documentation for public methods (intelisense). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the .xml file that contains the IntelliSense info for the assembly.  Make sure it is stored in the same directory as the reference assembly for these libraries, it has the same name as the assembly but with the .xml filename extension.  Maybe you forgot to copy it or cleaned-up too aggressively?